# Several new employees were hired into my team without me knowing

Tags: management

I've been working in this company for 1 year, as an IT Manager. I have an autocratic boss that dictates everything - even how you code your program, what hardware to buy, and software to buy - even though he is not an IT expert.

Recently, I felt bit strange/disturbed about the behaviour my boss has shown me. He suddenly hired more than 2 employee into my department without me knowing.

My questions here is: shouldn't there be some heads up? Or at least some kind of way for us to be informed that there will be someone joining the team?

Comment: Yes i'm not even aware and i do not know which part that i've done wrong and this affect my whole team, they got panic and worry they might get replaced. Is this some form of mis communication? coming from the Boss? What i see there should be some mutual understanding and respect that is lack from the boss

Comment: Sounds like you need to leave this job TBH!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere , from your opinion do you think its great to confront the boss and ask whats the reason?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not just a red flag that is a road flare.

He did not tell you head count was increasing nor include you in the hiring process? A non technical boss executed the hiring decision without your input?  I know look for new job is considered a last option but you need to consider putting out a resume.  If the job is otherwise tolerable then just roll with it (for a while).  An autocratic boss is typically happy if you just comply and they don't know how to measure actual output.  Do your (cookie cutter) job and add skills to get ready for the next job.  Move on when it is good for you.

Comment: thanks for your input and yes i am preparing to just quit. I'm tired of facing surprises and dysfunctional boss. Its mentally exhausted to keep up and think of any expectation that i could miss

Comment: Don't quit!  Stop caring and it becomes tolerable.  It is a paycheck.  Move  on when it is good for you.

Comment: Thanks @Papazzi, I'll take that advice,  I'll moved on anywhere when I'm ready

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a really bad idea waiting to happen. In addition to all the stuff that goes with you managing people you had no say in hiring and didn't even know had positions for (figuring out who will do what work, knowing what skillsets the different people have so that you can place them on the right projects, having no idea whether they'll fit into the culture of your existing group), I will bet a dollar that your boss will also expect these people to contribute right away and do so as full-fledged members of your team. Like, if you have 4 devs right now, he'll expect you to produce 50% more output immediately.

Needless to say, this isn't how things work (see: the Mythical Man-Month). And I don't think you're going to be able to explain this to your boss, because if your boss was the kind of person who listened to their subordinates he would have looped you in on the interview process or, you know, the fact that an interview process existed. So... good luck, I guess?

More seriously, this seems like the same advice folks give every time there's a problem, but this is one of these "polish up the resume and look for a better gig" situations. Get out before your reputation is tarnished by this guy.

Comment: Hi @NotVonKaiser :) noted on this and this makes me not very happy for couple of days now. But i think polishing up the CV and waiting for the right moment to move on is the right thing to do. It seems like working for the better boss is a way to go

Answer (score 0):

Reading your message, it occured to me there is a huge communication problem within you company and especially between you and your boss.

I would advice you to discuss with your boss, explain to him as manager you have to be involved in the recruitment process and that you wish you were aware of new recruitment projects. According to what he will answer you will have to chose to stay within this company or simply start looking for another job.

As a manager, part of your role is being involved in the recruitment process. Candidates you'll meet will be your potential new colleagues, you will have to manage everyday. You cannot work for someone who didn't understand this. It discredits your job position!

Comment: Hi @CMorgane42 , thanks for sharing the thoughts. These past few weeks i've paying a lot of attention at my work and also seek out a lot of advice from friends who are in management role. 

The results i found out is quite sad that many of the company do have a proper procedure and like you said manager always included in hiring process.

My boss probably think he is above all and not necessary to put any manager into hiring process where he think he can handle it himself. I found this to be unethical and lack of entrepreneur skill

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this is a pretty bad sign. A sign that the organization is dysfunctional, and that you're manager in name only.

I remember some of your previous questions (about working under a manager whom you didn't agree with, and how eventually you were put in charge and given free reign to go your own way) and am saddened to hear that now the situation has turned against you.

However, since you're new to management consider that this might be a telltale sign that your boss has some doubts regarding your abilities in this role (after all, you had quite a bit of freedom before). If I were you I would request a private meeting and try to discern whether this is the case, and whether he feels that you should be performing at a different level.

Establish expectations, and a process. He should be able to express what his goals are for yourself and the team, and you should be able to either admit that you require some help in meeting those goals, or that they are simply unattainable, and offer a reality-check/compromise. Also express how unhappy you are that you were kept out of the loop.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @AndreiRom, thanks for the input i will carry out this month to discuss about the expectation once again ... didn't put much hope into it but will do my best i know i'm new to management , i take this as a learning curve